# Why printed me one line in SWT Eclipse (Text). I wanted to print multi line in my Text

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Why printed me one line in SWT Eclipse (Text). I wanted to print multi line in my Text. That is my code. From my printer i got one line of my message instead of many rows in my print

```
Button btnPrint = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnPrint.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

             PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog(shell, SWT.MULTI| SWT.BORDER );
                printDialog.setText("Print");
                PrinterData printerData = printDialog.open();
                if (!(printerData == null)) {
                  Printer p = new Printer(printerData);
                  p.startJob("PrintJob");
                  p.startPage();

                Rectangle trim = p.computeTrim(0,0,0,0);
                  Point dpi = p.getDPI();
                  int leftMargin = dpi.x + trim.x;
                  int topMargin = dpi.y / 2 + trim.y;
                  GC gc = new GC(p);
                  Font font = gc.getFont();
                  String printText = text.getText();
                  Point extent = gc.stringExtent(printText);

                  gc.drawString(printText, leftMargin, topMargin+ font.getFontData()[0].getHeight());
                  p.endPage();
                  gc.dispose();
                  p.endJob();
                  p.dispose();
                }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`gc.drawString` does not look for line delimiters.

Use `gc.drawText`:

```
public void drawText(String string, int x, int y)
```

which does look for line delimiters (and tabs). Or use

```
public void drawText(String string, int x, int y, int flags)
```

and specify `SWT.DRAW_DELIMITER` for the `flags` value